# Install Oracle on docker centos container: Insufficient disk space

Tags: oracle11g, centos, docker

I try to install oracle 11g in a docker container. The container was build from centos:6 image. The host is a fedora21.

The oracle installer (/opt/oracle/database/runInstaller) complains about Insufficient disk space:

```
SEVERE: [FATAL] [INS-32021] Insufficient disk space on this volume for the selected Oracle home.
CAUSE: The selected Oracle home was on a volume without enough disk space.
ACTION: Choose a location for Oracle home that has enough space (minimum of 4,324MB) or free up space on the existing volume.
```

Indeed the space reported by docker is not enough:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                9.8G  5.4G  3.9G  58% /
/dev/mapper/docker-253:0-1315729-b9ba9f0049753e5d7cb7e0fc64f68af92a4f9972a8d5e4988acce418bb4a88aa
tmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
shm                    64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/fedora_lap--alainsavio-root
                   50G   21G   27G  45% /etc/resolv.conf
```

Can I tell docker to allocate (or report?) more disk space for this container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.
Finally, what worked was:

```
$ sudo service docker stop
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
$ sudo service docker start
```

! This removes all local docker images and containers.

Edit the file /etc/sysconfig/docker ad modify the OPTIONS parameter:

```
# Modify these options if you want to change the way the docker daemon runs
OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled --storage-driver=devicemapper --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G'
```

See https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#daemon-storage-driver-option

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have more than the default of 10 Gb for a container, see this article https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/01/29/docker-device-mapper-resize/

Comment: this CentOS/Oracle image uses the standard 10 Gb, see https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ariya/centos7-oracle-jre7/dockerfile/

Comment: Thanks. I was actually hoping that the procedure in that article was not the solution. If that is the solution, it means that I cannot just provide a Dockerfile so my users can build their containers. They need to go through that extremely complicated process to re-size the volume.

Comment: @esalagea only if your users are also using devicemapper. You could also provide an image for them to download to sidestep the issue.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. So If I understand well: if I increase the volume of the container and then create an image from it, the users of the image will be able to use the image as it is, without any additional device hacking, even if they use device mapper. I will try this.

Comment: @esalagea Yeah, that should work. I think you need more space to create the image than you do to run it.

Comment: Well, the procedure in Growing Containers section  from https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/01/29/docker-device-mapper-resize/ does not work. If the container is not running (like in the example in the article) there is not partition in  /dev/mapper. If the container is running, everything works fine, but it fails in the end when resizing the fs with resize2fs: resize2fs: 
Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/mapper/....
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

Comment: extract from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/xb7z8SgSfXs  1) using a different backend (AUFS or BTRFS)
By starting docker with "-s aufs" or "-s btrfs"

2) using "storage-opt" to increase the devicemapper default size
By starting docker with "--storage-opt dm.basesize=50G"
See https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/daemon/graphdriver/devmapper for more details about storage-opt.

Answer (score 0):

Modify Docker options in the `/etc/default/docker` file on host.

`DOCKER_OPTS="--storage-driver=devicemapper --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G"`

(!) The existing containers and images may be lost.